# Запятая, тире или двоеточие - что правильно?

Tags: пунктуация

Наш регион особенный в силу своей этнической специфики(,) у нас проживает много казахов...
Правильно ли стоит запятая в скобках (хочется тире или двоеточие)?
Похожий вопрос по заголовку вопроса (тире или двоеточие).

Comment: Уважаемый автор!  Пожалуйста, приведите полный текст предложения.

Comment: Наш регион особенный в силу своей этнической специфики(,) у нас проживает много казахов, и поэтому исламские книги, которые переведены на казахский язык, пользуются здесь повышенным интересом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы поставила двоеточие:первая часть сложного предложения с разными видами связи -  бессоюзное сложное предложение, второе простое раскрывает содержание первого, поясняет его.

*Наш регион особенный в силу своей этнической специфики: у нас проживает много казахов, и поэтому исламские книги, которые переведены на казахский язык, пользуются здесь повышенным интересом.*

Можно оправдать и скобки: вставная конструкция -  попутное замечание, пояснение по поводу особенности.

*Наш регион особенный в силу своей этнической специфики(у нас проживает много казахов), и поэтому исламские книги, которые переведены на казахский язык, пользуются здесь повышенным интересом*.

Кстати, иногда, в редких случаях, вставные конструкции выделяются и запятыми: *Мне показалось даже, а может быть оно и в самом деле было так, что все стали к нам ласковее (Аксаков).* **Так что запятые тоже возможны.**

Тире, думаю, не очень уместно, ведь оно придает эмоционально-экспрессивную окраску, динамику, а здесь это не очень уместно.

Тире в заголовке вопроса корректно, предложение можно считать неполным,по смыслу оно содержит обобщающее слово: "всё это", "перечень" или "знаки препинания"

*Запятая, тире или двоеточие - что (из этого перечня) правильно?*

Answer (score 2):

Ответ исправлен.

Я считаю, что постановка **двоеточия при сохранении запятой** в принятом ответе – **это ошибочное решение.**

Здесь возможно разное деление на смысловые блоки.

**Вариант 1 (2+2, с запятой и тире)**

Наш регион особенный в силу своей этнической специфики – у нас проживает много казахов,  и поэтому исламские книги, которые переведены на казахский язык, пользуются здесь повышенным интересом.

**Вариант 2 (1+3, с двоеточием и без запятой)**

(2) Наш регион особенный в силу своей ЭТНИЧЕСКОЙ специфики:  у нас проживает много КАЗАХОВ  и поэтому исламские книги, которые переведены на КАЗАХСКИЙ язык, пользуются здесь повышенным интересом.

**Комментарий**

1. Для варианта 1 двоеточие не подходит,  так как это **остановка голоса и длительная пауза (причем в середине предложения!),** и всё это ради короткого добавочного пояснения.   Здесь интонация должна быть присоединительной,  то есть ставится **присоединительное**  **тире.** Оно, кстати, не содержит **ни динамики, ни экспрессии, ни особых эмоций** – ну ничего такого, о чем здесь говорилось.
2. Для варианта 2 двоеточие обозначает **предупредительную  паузу**, после которой   следуют **три СВЯЗАННЫХ между собой предложения, поясняющих общую ситуацию В ЦЕЛОМ,** а не только  большое количество казахов.
3. **О постановке запятой не может быть и речи,** так как в первом предложении присутствует слово "особенный", требующее разъяснения, а не простого перечисления информации через запятую.
4. И уж совершенно напрасно приводятся примеры, **не имеющие никакого отношения к структуре данного предложения,** из которых делается вывод **о возможности постановки запятой.**

Comment: Не могу согласиться, что можно опустить наречие "поэтому", ведь без него вообще не понятно, почему книги, которые переведены на казахский язык, пользуются здесь повышенным интересом. И насчет запятой перед союзом И: по-моему, связь между вторым предложением осуществляется именно с пояснением (это же главная причина повышенного интереса), а не с первым предложением.

Comment: По поводу наречия не настаиваю, а запятая при наличии двоеточия нежелательна. Объяснение в ответе.  Запятая  не подойдет, здесь нужен более сильный знак (двоеточие или тире)